# GCP credentials with skaffold for local development

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, skaffold

What is the standard approach to getting GCP credentials into k8s pods when using skaffold for local development?

When I previously used docker compose and aws it was easy to volume mount the ~/.aws folder to the container and everything just worked. Is there an equivalent solution for skaffold and gcp?

Comment: As far as I understand you want to be able to use **cloud sdk** or comunicate in any other way with **GCP API** from locally deployed `Pods` by **skaffold**, right ?

Comment: Correct, I want the GCP API code that I run locally to have the same permissions on a local skaffold-deployed pod. What I am doing right now is putting a service account file in the root of the project and copying it in the Dockerfile, which means manual steps for other developers which isn't ideal.

Comment: Hey, were you able to find an answer to that?

Comment: The best I could come up with was to create a service account JSON and copy it over in the dockerfile, setting the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env var to point to it.

Answer (score 2):

> When I previously used docker compose and aws it was easy to volume
> mount the ~/.aws folder to the container and everything just worked.
> Is there an equivalent solution for skaffold and gcp?

You didn't mention what kind of **kubernetes cluster** you have deployed locally but if you use **Minikube** it can be actually achieved in a very similar way.

Supposed you have already initialized your **Cloud SDK** locally by running:

```
gcloud auth login
gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster name> --zone <zone> --project <project name>
gcloud config set project <project name>
```

so you can run your `gcloud commands` on the local machine on which **Minikube** is installed. You can easily delagate this access to your `Pods` created either by **Skakffold** or manually on **Minikube**.

You just need to start your **Minikube** as follows:

```
minikube start --mount=true --mount-string="$HOME/.config/gcloud/:/home/docker/.config/gcloud/"
```

To make things simple I'm mounting local **Cloud SDK** config directory into **Minikube** host using as a mount point `/home/docker/.config/gcloud/`.

Once it is available on **Minikube host VM**, it can be easily mounted into any `Pod`. We can use one of the **Cloud SDK** docker images available [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/google/cloud-sdk/) or any other image that comes with **Cloud SDK** preinstalled.

Sample `Pod` to test this out may look like the one below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod 
metadata:
  name: cloud-sdk-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - image: google/cloud-sdk:alpine
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'sleep 3600']
    name: cloud-sdk-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /root/.config/gcloud
      name: gcloud-volume
  volumes:
  - name: gcloud-volume
    hostPath:
      # directory location on host
      path: /home/docker/.config/gcloud
      # this field is optional
      type: Directory
```

After connecting to the `Pod` by running:

```
kubectl exec -ti cloud-sdk-pod -- /bin/bash
```

we'll be able to execute any `gcloud` commands as we are able to execute them on our local machine.

Comment: I would change `<project name>` to `<project id>` in your google cloud API calls

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Skaffold with a Minikube cluster then you can use their `gcp-auth` addon which does exactly this, described [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/addons/gcp-auth/) in detail.